# How could I make a VDB volume not cast shadows?

Tags: lighting, shadows, volumetrics

I imported a VDB volume from Houdini into Blender 2.92 and it creates some weird shadows. How could I make it not cast any shadows? I went into Visibility > Ray Tracing but there's no Shadow tickbox.

Here's the glitch I want to remove:

[image]

Here's the render:

[image]

If I remove the VDB mesh, the shadow disappears. So yes, it is being casted by the volume mesh somehow. Perhaps by its bounds? I don't know.

Here's the viewport:

[image]

Here's the glitchy part without the VDB mesh. No more lines:

[image]

Here are the bounds from above. They don't perfectly match with the lines:

[image]

Here's the viewport from above:

[image]

Comment: Can you show me a picture of the correct version? The glitch could be a number of things in the current picture.

Comment: What do you mean by 'correct version'?

Comment: The version without the glitch. More clearly, the version where the volume is hidden. Possibly also add circling on the problem version to show exactly where and what the problem is.

Comment: I updated the image. Now it should be more clear.

Comment: The shadows which shouldn't be there are the two lines.

Comment: I see. OK, now, where is the volume, and where is the scene light?

Comment: I added a picture of the whole render.

Comment: The light comes from the right and it's a Sun lamp.

Comment: The bounds of the VDB mesh extend roughly to where the lines are.

Comment: Wait, I'll add a picture of the viewport.

Comment: I see  That is strange. Here’s a diagnostic you could do. Click on the shadow to put the 3-D cursor there, and add a new camera object. Then, use a track to constraint on the camera to point it at the sun. Last of all, go into that camera’s view (use the view menu to set it as the active camera), and switch through the different viewport modes.

Comment: I updated the post with more images to describe the situation. Maybe they could help. What do you think?